# What happened to David John Candlin?

Tags: soft-question, history

This is an ultra-soft question about relatively recent history. While reading some of Mandelstam's papers, I noticed that he cites David John Candlin consistenly whenever he does anything with Grassman path-integral. Everyone else cites Berezin.

So I read Candlin's 1956 paper, and I was stunned to find a complete and correct description of anticommuting variables, presented more lucidly than anywhere else, with a clear definition of Grassman integration, and a proof that it reproduces the Fermionic quantum field. This is clearly the original source of all the Grassman methods. I was stunned that the inventor of this method is quietly buried away.

I wrote the [Wikipedia page on the guy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_John_Candlin), but I couldn't find out anything beyond the sketchy stuff I found on an old Princeton staff listing. The fellow doesn't google very well at all.

Here are the questions:

- Is he still alive? (Hello? Are you there?)
- Did he become the experimental physicist David John Candlin in the late 1970s/early 1980s? Or is this someone else with the same name?
- Did he get any credit for his discovery?

I mean, this is one of the central tools of modern physics, it is used every day by every theorist, and the inventor is never mentioned. It's 50% of the path integral. Why the silence?

Comment: This question's assertion about the Wikipedia page is rather puzzling. The [edit history](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=David_John_Candlin&action=history) of the linked article shows no activity on 2012, at which point it was already substantially in its current form, and no apparent activity by OP.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Not really. The page was originally created in 2008, by a user who seems enough like Ron that I'm inclined to believe his claim that they are the same person.

Comment: @Chris Goodness, you're right. I hadn't looked at that profile page.

Answer (score 37):

I googled a little bit a while ago, and found him. I didn't get any insights into the history of this discovery, he didn't respond to my email. The person I contacted in order to reach him was eventually so offended by my rude email questions that he told me to buzz off. I am only posting this because the guy obviously wants his privacy, and one should respect this. I saw the bounty, and thought people are going to pester this guy in retirement.

Comment: Your journey through Mandelstam’s work and follow up on references to Candlin’s work is admirable. I would preferred to have learned this way rather than reading results in textbooks.